# Trigger update product quantity

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update the quantity of Product items in the product_stock table (when an UPDATE occurs in the Product table it will update the Product quantity in the product_stock table). But the error is running -> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'product.id_product' in 'where clause'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product`(
    `id_product`INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    `unitarya_value`DECIMAL NOT NULL,    
    `minimum_quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY(`id_product`))    
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_product`(
    `id_stock_product`INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    `current_quantity`INT(11) NOT NULL,   
    `id_product`INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY(`id_stock_product`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`id_product`)
    REFERENCES `product` (`id_product`)    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateProductquantity
BEFORE UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE qtt INT DEFAULT 50;
    UPDATE stock_product set current_quantity = current_quantity + qtt
    WHERE stock_product.id_product = product.id_product ; 
END; $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, the columns from the `product` table are prefixed with `NEW.column` and `OLD.column`, not the table name itself, so the last part of the `WHERE` clause could be:

```
WHERE stock_product.id_product = NEW.id_product ;
```

Also, as a side-note: unless there are other plans with the `qtt` variable, you could use the `50` value in the `SET` clause without a variable:

```
UPDATE stock_product SET current_quantity = current_quantity + 50
```